# Did Aharon Hakohen have a higher level of prophecy?

Tags: moshe-rabbeinu, nevua-prophecy, navi-prophets

The Rambam Yesodei Hatorah (7:2) [writes](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Foundations_of_the_Torah.7.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

> הַנְּבִיאִים מַעֲלוֹת מַעֲלוֹת הֵן. כְּמוֹ שֶׁיֵּשׁ בַּחָכְמָה חָכָם
> גָּדוֹל מֵחֲבֵרוֹ כָּךְ בַּנְּבוּאָה נָבִיא גָּדוֹל מִנָּבִיא.
> וְכֻלָּן אֵין רוֹאִין מַרְאֵה הַנְּבוּאָה אֶלָּא בַּחֲלוֹם בְּחֶזְיוֹן
> לַיְלָה. אוֹ בַּיּוֹם אַחַר שֶׁתִּפּל עֲלֵיהֶן תַּרְדֵּמָה כְּמוֹ
> שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר (במדבר יב ו) "בַּמַּרְאָה אֵלָיו אֶתְוַדָּע בַּחֲלוֹם
> אֲדַבֶּר בּוֹ". וְכֻלָּן **כְּשֶׁמִּתְנַבְּאִים אֵיבְרֵיהֶן
> מִזְדַּעְזְעִין וְכֹחַ הַגּוּף כָּשֵׁל וְעֶשְׁתּוֹנוֹתֵיהֶם
> מִתְטָרְפוֹת** וְתִשָּׁאֵר הַדַּעַת פְּנוּיָה לְהָבִין מַה שֶּׁתִּרְאֶה.
> כְּמוֹ שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר בְּאַבְרָהָם (בראשית טו יב) "וְהִנֵּה אֵימָה
> חֲשֵׁכָה גְדלָה נֹפֶלֶת עָלָיו". וּכְמוֹ שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר בְּדָנִיֵּאל
> (דניאל י ח) "וְהוֹדִי נֶהְפַּךְ עָלַי לְמַשְׁחִית וְלֹא עָצַרְתִּי
> כֹּחַ" - Prophets are of various degrees. Even as there is in wisdom,
> one wise man greater than his fellow, so it is in prophecy, one
> prophet is greater than another prophet. But all of them do not see
> the vision of prophecy save in a dream, in a vision by night, or
> during the day when a deep slumber falls upon them, as it is said: "I
> become known to him in vision; I speak to him in a dream" (Num. 12.6).
> **And they all, when they prophesy, tremble in all their limbs, the
> strength of their bodies gives way, their thinking power becomes
> unbalanced,** the sense of understanding alone remains open to grasp
> what it will see, as it is said of Abraham: "And behold, a great
> trembling and darkness befell upon him" (Gen. 15.12); and as it is
> said of Daniel: "For my comeliness was turned into corruption, and I
> retained no strength" (Dan. 10.8).

On the other hand, the Rambam (7:6) [writes](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Foundations_of_the_Torah.7.6?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) regarding Moshe Rabbeinu

> כָּל הַדְּבָרִים שֶׁאָמַרְנוּ הֵם דֶּרֶךְ נְבוּאָה לְכָל הַנְּבִיאִים
> הָרִאשׁוֹנִים וְהָאַחֲרוֹנִים חוּץ מִמּשֶׁה רַבֵּנוּ רַבָּן שֶׁל כָּל
> הַנְּבִיאִים. וּמַה הֶפְרֵשׁ יֵשׁ בֵּין נְבוּאַת משֶׁה לִשְׁאָר כָּל
> הַנְּבִיאִים. שֶׁכָּל הַנְּבִיאִים בַּחֲלוֹם אוֹ בְּמַרְאֶה וּמשֶׁה
> רַבֵּנוּ מִתְנַבֵּא וְהוּא עֵר וְעוֹמֵד שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר (במדבר ז פט)
> "וּבְבֹא משֶׁה אֶל אֹהֶל מוֹעֵד לְדַבֵּר אִתּוֹ וַיִּשְׁמַע אֶת
> הַקּוֹל מִדַּבֵּר אֵלָיו" - All the things hereinof spoken is the path
> of prophecy for all prophets, First and Last, save Moses our Master,
> the Master of all prophets. And what division is there between the
> prophecy of Moses and that of all the other prophets? All the other
> prophets prophesied while in a dream, or in a vision, but Moses our
> **Master prophesied while awake and standing up, as it is said: "And
> when Moses went into the tent of meeting that He might speak with Him,**
> then he heard the Voice speaking unto him" (Num. 7.89); all other
> prophets received it through an Angel, they therefore saw what they
> did see in the form of allegory and riddles, but Moses our Master did
> not receive it through an angel, for it is said: "With him do I speak
> mouth to mouth" (Ibid. 12.8), and it is also said: "and the Lord spoke
> unto Moses face to face" (Ex. 33.11);

Seemingly, when Moshe Rabbeinu and Aharon Hakohen stood side-by-side and received a prophecy from Hashem, Moshe heard the prophecy as if speaking with another person while Aharon was unconsciously rolling on the ground. Was this what actually happened on each occasion or do commentators explain that Aharon HaKohen had a higher form of prophecy than others as well?

Comment: [Rashi on Vayikra 11:1, s.v. "אל משה ואל אהרן",](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Leviticus.11.1?lang=bi&p2=Rashi_on_Leviticus.11.1&lang2=bi) says that "_He_ (i.e. Hashem) _spoke to Moses that he should in turn tell Aaron_". See also [Rashi on Vayikra 1:1, s.v. "אליו"](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Leviticus.1.1?lang=bi&p2=Rashi_on_Leviticus.1.1.3&lang2=bi). Did Aharon Hakohen receive prophecy directly from Hashem?

Comment: The Rambam would have said so in those perakim

Comment: This is discussed towards the end of the shiur here: https://nirc.edu/behaloscha5781/